# Why can't I use mysqldump command in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cron, user-defined-functions, stored-functions

I want to do:

```
  delimiter //
  create procedure backup(IN filepath varchar(100),IN password varchar(100))
  deterministic
  begin
  set @db=database();     
  mysqldump -u current_user() -ppassword  @db >filepath; #This line, I think is dangerous
  end //
```

Then from an event I will call it once a day.
Can I do it or not..if not this way then what r the other ways in stored procedure or function?

Comment: Aw..I'm in great trouble man.. I want to do the stored procedure or user defined function (UDF) way. Please answer If anyone knows about it..I'm just craving for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

First, in a store procedure, you can only write SQL instructions.
Mysqldump is a shell command.
Also, I don't think you can run mysqldump while there is a function is use. In this case, your store procedure. If it was possible, you will have a dead lock for sure.
Finaly, this is a serious security breach if it was possible.

Comment: Do u know how to do it from the native sql capability?